# POST request from python to rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write an integration from a Python script to a rails app.

I want this POST request to send a proper params hash, like what Rails typically wants for a POST request. But currently I'm just able to send the parameters bare, i.e:

```
Parameters: {"review_site_id"=>"31", "location_id"=>"23", "subdomain"=>"api"}
```

What I want is:

```
Parameters: {"review" => {"review_site_id"=>"31", "location_id"=>"23", "subdomain"=>"api"}}
```

My python code:

```
    review = {
      'review_site_id': 31,
      'location_id': 23
    }
    mydata = urllib.urlencode(review)
    mydata = mydata.encode('utf-8')
    path = 'http://api.mysite.dev:3000/reviews'
    req = urllib2.Request(path, mydata)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Thanks in advance for any help / insights

Answer (score 0):

It is sending `params` hash, try this code

```
review = {'review': {
  'review_site_id': 31,
  'location_id': 23
}}
```